# Как сделать быстрее код Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Столкнулся с таком задачей пользователь вводит k число которое обозначает номер  магического числа в последовательности. Магическим называется число сумма цифр которого равна 10.
A. Магическое число
Ограничение времени 0.1 секунд
Ограничение памяти  5.0 Мб

Будем называть положительное целое число «магическим», если сумма его цифр равна 10.
Вам дано целое число k, найдите k-ое по величине «магическое» целое число.

Формат ввода
Пользователь вводит целое число
k (
1
≤
k
≤
10000
1≤k≤10000).

Формат вывода
Выведите k-ое по величине «магическое» число.

Пример 1
Ввод    Вывод
1
19
Пример 2
Ввод    Вывод
2
28
Пример 3
Ввод    Вывод
3
37

Не знаю как ускорить еще свой код не поппадаю в тайм

```
k = int(input())
count = 0
number = 18
while count != k:
    tmp = str(number)
    suma = 0
    for i in tmp:
        t = int(i)
        suma += t
    if suma == 10:
        count += 1
        number += 1
    else:
        number += 1
print(number-1)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что можно сделать

Comment: Ну число в строку вовсе не нужно переводить, чтобы посчитать сумму его цифр. Однако всё равно перебор всех чисел - это тупиковый путь. Нужно подумать, у каких чисел нужная сумма цифр и сгенерировать k-е из них

Comment: Я сейчас тоже смотрю есть варик прыжки совершать но вопрос в if будет ли он замедлять сам процесс . Буду сидеть проверять . Если поменьше выйдет подгружу

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, не нужно удалять метку [tag:python-3.x] в вопросах.

Answer (score 4):

придумал еще один алгоритм (его надо доработать - сейчас он выдает чуть другой результат, но принцип правильный), скорость работы **0.04 сек** (для k = 10000)

основной смысл:

1. получаем все возможные комбинации цифр 1-9, которые в сумме дают 10
2. начинаем формировать все возможные комбинации этих цифр с нулями, увеличивая кол-во нулей
3. из цифр собираем числа и заносим их в список (вот тут и надо допилить алгоритм, чтобы только уникальные числа добавлять в список)
4. когда в списке k значений - забираем самое большое

код:

```
# получить все возможные варианты цифр
def func(value, digits, res):
    if value <= 0:
        if value == 0:
            res.append(digits)
    else:
        for i in range(digits[-1] if digits else 1, 10):
            func(value - i, digits + [i], res)

variants = []
func(10, [], variants)

# собрать все возможные комбинации с 0 найденных вариантов цифр
numbers = []

size = 2
while True:
    # для заданного кол-ва цифр в числе рассмотреть все возможные варианты цифр с суммой 10
    for variant in variants:
        # вычислить кол-во нулей в числе
        zero_count = size - len(variant)
        if zero_count < 0:
            continue
            
        # получить все возможные комбинации цифр
        nums = set(itertools.permutations(variant + [0] * zero_count))

        for num in nums:
            # рассматривать комбинации не начинающиеся с 0
            if num[0] != 0:
                # сформировать из цифр число
                value = 0
                for digit in num:
                    value = value * 10 + digit

                # добавить число в список найденных магических чисел
                numbers.append(value)
                if len(numbers) > k:
                    print(sorted(numbers)[k - 1])
                    return

    size += 1
```

для k = 10000 алгоритм работает **0,04 сек** и находит 61111000, хотя правильный ответ 10800100 - надо подумать почему

Нашел проблему - не рассмариваются все числа (не успевают) - если сделать так:

вместо:

```
if len(numbers) > k:
```

надо

```
if len(numbers) > 2 * k:
```

то все работает!

**вариант 2:**

Вариант даёт ГАРАНТИРОВАННЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ, но поэтому работает помедленнее (**0,15 сек**)

```
# получить все возможные варианты цифр
def func(value, digits, res):
    if value == 0:
        res.append(digits)
    else:
        for i in range(digits[-1] if digits else 1, 10):
            if value >= i:
                func(value - i, digits + [i], res)

variants = []
func(10, [], variants)


# собрать все возможные комбинации с 0 найденных вариантов цифр
count = 0
size = 2

while True:
    # для заданного кол-ва цифр в числе рассмотреть все возможные варианты цифр с суммой 10
    nums = []
    for variant in variants:
        # вычислить кол-во нулей в числе
        zero_count = size - len(variant)
        if zero_count < 0:
            continue

        # получить все возможные комбинации цифр
        for num in set(itertools.permutations(variant + [0] * zero_count)):
            # рассматривать комбинации не начинающиеся с 0
            if num[0] != 0:
                # сформировать из цифр число
                value = 0
                for digit in num:
                    value = value * 10 + digit

                nums.append(value)

    # если искомое число присутствует в найденных числах - найти его
    if len(nums) + count >= k:
        print(sorted(nums)[k - count - 1])
        return

    # увеличить размер искомых чисел
    count += len(nums)
    size += 1
```

Comment: Классно и относительно несложно!

Answer (score 4):

Для серьезных значений `k` перебор не подойдёт, нужен алгоритм, генерирующий нужное число.

Используем метод **stars and bars** ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)). У нас имеется 10 единиц, обозначаемых звёздочками. Между ними мы можем ставить `m` перегородок (bars). Эти перегородки могут находиться в любом из 9 внутренних промежутков между звездочками, а также справа.

```
*    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    * 
       |              ||                        |
```

Единственное ограничение -  все `m` перегородок не могут быть одновременно справа. Что же означает какое либо расположение? Это `m+1`-значное десятичное число. Чтобы его получить, просто считаем количество звездочек между перегородками. Например, выше изображено пятизначное число 23050. Ограничение означает, что у нас нет цифры `десять'

Сколько существует нужных нам `m`-значных чисел? По ссылке выше - `число k-кортежей неотрицательных целых чисел, сумма которых равна n`, и отнимем один ненужный нам случай, когда все перегородки справа:

```
F(m)  = С(9+m-1, m-1) - 1
```

(`C(n,k)` - формула из комбинаторики для количества сочетаний). Таким образом, есть 9 двузначных, 54 трёхзначных, 219 четырехзначных, 714 пятизначных чисел и так далее.

Используя данную формулу, мы можем посчитать 9+54+219... пока сумма не превысит k, т.е. быстро определим, сколько цифр в искомом числе. Далее можно генерировать нужную комбинацию через сочетания, и перевести её в число.

А вот и код:

```
def cnk(n, k):  # math.comb для Python 3.8+
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k <= 0:
        return 1 if k == 0 else 0
    res = 1
    for i in range(k):
        res = res * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return res

def num2comb(n, k, m):  #получение сочетания по его номеру в лекс. порядке
    res = []
    next = 1
    while k > 0:
        cn = cnk(n - 1, k - 1)
        if m < cn:
            res.append(next)
            k -= 1
        else:
            m -= cn
        n -= 1
        next += 1
    return res

def fun(k):
    s = 0
    m = 1
    while s < k:
        m += 1
        last = s
        s += cnk(8 + m, m - 1) - 1
    kk = k - last  #порядковый номер среди m-значных чисел

    comb = num2comb(8 + m, m - 1, kk - 1) + [9 + m]
    v = comb[0]
    for i in range(len(comb) - 1):
        v = v * 10 + comb[i + 1] - comb[i] - 1
    return v

print(fun(10000))

>>> 10800100
```

Время логарифмическое от `k`. Для k=10000 и мерить нечего, микросекунды.

Чтобы получить заметное время работы, примерно одну секунду, понадобится  k=100000000000000000000000000000000000000000, результат  сюда не поместится

Comment: `cnk` -> [math.comb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb).

Comment: @Stanislav Оно в 3.8 появилось, ещё непривычно

Answer (score 1):

итак - проверяю на `k = 10000`, исходный алгоритм автора - **12сек**

**вариант 1 [10сек] (используем стандартные функции работы со списками и строками):**

```
count = 0
number = 18
while count != k:
    s = sum(map(int, str(number)))
    if s == 10:
        count += 1
    number += 1
print(number-1)
```

**вариант 2 [6 сек] (работа с цифрами числа, а не со строкой):**

```
count = 0
number = 18
while count != k:
    s = 0
    tmp = number
    while tmp != 0:
        s += tmp % 10
        tmp //= 10
    if s == 10:
        count += 1
    number += 1
print(number-1)
```

**вариант 3 [3.8 сек] (вариант 2, но отсекаем вычисление суммы, если она стала выше 10):**

```
count = 0
number = 18
while count != k:
    s = 0
    tmp = number
    while tmp != 0:
        s += tmp % 10
        tmp //= 10
        if s > 10:
            break
    if s == 10:
        count += 1
    number += 1
print(number-1)
```

**вариант 3.1 [3.45 сек] (вариант 3, но не делаем лишнюю операцию деления когда цикл вычисления цифр прерывается):**

```
count = 0
number = 18
while count != k:
    s = 0
    tmp = number
    while tmp != 0:
        s += tmp % 10
        if s > 10:
            break
        tmp //= 10
    if s == 10:
        count += 1
    number += 1
print(number-1)
```

**вариант 4 [3.1 сек] (экономим на спичках - проверку на условие выхода из цикла делаем только когда это условие надо проверять, а не всегда):**

```
count = 0
number = 18
while True:
    s = 0
    tmp = number
    while tmp != 0:
        s += tmp % 10
        if s > 10:
            break
        tmp //= 10
    if s == 10:
        count += 1
        if count == k:
            print(number)
            return
    number += 1
```

**вариант 5 [0.5сек]:**

логика чуть посложнее - если сумма цифр больше 10, то все числа с последней цифрой до следующего 0 можно не рассматривать, потому что сумма будет только расти

например если у xxxx4 сумма 11, то числа `xxxx5`, `xxxx6`, `xxxx7`, `xxxx8`, `xxxx9` можно уже не рассматривать и переходить к числу `xxxy0`

```
count = 0
number = 18
while True:
    s = 0
    tmp = number
    while tmp != 0:
        s += tmp % 10
        if s > 10:
            break
        tmp //= 10
    if s > 10:
        number = (number // 10) * 10 + 10
    else:
        if s == 10:
            count += 1
            if count == k:
                print(number)
                return
        number += 1
```

Comment: Я вот это всё тоже попробовал, но ограничение то 0.1с, так что это всё без толку, всё-равно нужно формулу выводить, одними оптимизациями не влезает )

Comment: да, надо подумать, но скорее всего логика в том, что чем больше число, тем реже будут встречаться магические числа и можно перескакивать целые диапазоны

Comment: можете ускорить ещё, начав с 19 и делая `number += 9`. Однако при серьезных k это всё равно не поможет

Comment: ^ это первое, что в голову приходит, и ускорят почти в 10 раз. но может, и недостаточно

Comment: а у меня наоборот - это в несколько раз замедлило относительно варианта 5

Comment: @Zhihar Значит, вы там дальше прыгаете типа 9010000=>9100000

Comment: А вы азартный ) А почему код для 1 и 2 варианта один и тот же?

Comment: глюк какой-то, странно, исправил

Comment: https://tio.run/##hVHLboMwELz7K/YSCdLQYPVSITlf0VvVQ9MujQUsyDaq2p@nazs45hB1D8Yz@/DMMv24y0hPy/KJLXwVVDYCOAgUWGcYB2j1LzLTI62ML9DkCnptmkq@RTIcmjN17Eq374vuESjOjqkHxTN2IOvE6ZbpEzO3Mh9ng@9dYgiOR7Xp8pNkgAbdbCiKrUAfwArhbbVFd7X1Mc7kkiqahzMahvI5U/liZrwpoEOwwZsJxeV/av1eZA37PdCWj28F19WKdlkR9habOy08sGIzeTI6SdYzVVePCrrtuGxDcfK9xxIv9DCNxoHTAwphlf8@@qMoxWT8328LWXOUK84qACpbLssf данный код вроде укладывается во время

Answer (score 1):

Zhinar вот что получилось меньше 0.1 секунды алгоритмы просто ушли гулять

```
def checking(n: int) -> bool:
    r = 0
    while n:
        r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
        if r > 10:
            break
    return True if (r == 10) else False
 
 
magic_number = int(input())
if magic_number >= 9212:
    count = 9212
    i = 10200007
elif magic_number >= 7996:
    count = 7996
    i = 9000001
elif magic_number >= 7975:
    count = 7975
    i = 8000002
elif magic_number >= 7919:
    count = 7919
    i = 7000003
elif magic_number >= 7793:
    count = 7793
    i = 6000004
elif magic_number >= 7541:
    count = 7541
    i = 5000005
elif magic_number >= 7079:
    count = 7079
    i = 4000006
elif magic_number >= 6287:
    count = 6287
    i = 3000007
elif magic_number >= 5000:
    count = 5000
    i = 2000008
elif magic_number >= 4705:
    count = 4705
    i = 1322020
elif magic_number >= 3000:
    count = 3000
    i = 1000027
elif magic_number >= 2747:
    count = 2747
    i = 500005
elif magic_number >= 2000:
    count = 2000
    i = 220033
else:
    count = 1
    i = 19
 
while True:
    summ = 0
    if count == magic_number:
        print(str(i))
        break
    i = i + 9
    if checking(i):
        count += 1
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: да, через таблицы сделать можно, но это все таки не совсем корректный подход, хотя...

Comment: Если это ответ, соберите все в один ответ, а не плодите комментарии как ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вариант:

```
def A051885(n):
    return ((n % 9) + 1) * 10 ** (n // 9) - 1


def A228915(n):
    p = r = 0
    while True:
        d = n % 10
        if d < 9 and r:
            return (n + 1) * 10**p + A051885(r - 1)
        n //= 10
        r += d
        p += 1


def A052224(N=19):
    """Return a generator of the sequence of all integers >= N with the same

    digit sum as N."""

    while True:
        yield N
        N = A228915(N)

k = int(input())
for i, _ in zip(A052224(19), range(k)):
    pass
print(i)
```

[A052224](https://oeis.org/A052224)
[A228915](https://oeis.org/A228915)
[A051885](https://oeis.org/A051885)

Comment: Работает за O(k) (если не учитывать длину чисел). Для указанных ограничений -  вполне.